# find first record with a specific value in list box

Tags: vba, ms-access

Lets say I have two list boxes, the first one is:

```
ID | Name1 | Name2
 1    dcf    jkl
```

and the second is

```
ID_1 | Name1 | Addr
 1    abc     add1
 2    dcf     add2
 3    cde     add1
 4    dcf     add2
```

lets say I want to see if "dcf" name1 is in the 2nd list box. Essentially, if "dcf" is in the 2nd listbox anywhere, set it active, and then do this, else, do something else. I'm familiar with writing the if statements and what I need inside of it, what I can't seem to figure out is how to just search is "dcf" is in the 2nd list box.

Comment: Generally this type of thing would be done by generating an SQL query "On Update" of the first drop and set that to be the "Row Source" of the second dropdown.  Though this will generally only work if you are using bound dropdown boxes.

Comment: naw...not a dropdown box, just a list box....

Comment: Sorry, same thing, list box or combo box.  Just use the "On Update" event of the first list box to generate an SQL query based off of the selected field of the first list box.  Then set it as the row source of the second list box.  Someone will probably come along shortly and post an example, I am just not great at writing SQL free hand.  Don't forget to upvote/accept their answer.  If someone else doesn't come along in the next hour or so I will throw up my best shot at an example.

Comment: What do you intend to do if there is more than one record with dcf in the Name1 field?  This will affect if your best option is to use SQL or just a for each loop.

Comment: well, I just need to know if any records exist with "dcf". if they do, then I need to set a variable that equals the addr value. so in this case...var1 = "add2"

Comment: Okay, give me a few minutes and I will see if I can some up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something like what you are looking for. Obviously the code would need to be adjusted to do what you want it to once it finds the record and also your naming scheme, but the structure is there.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs       As Recordset
    Dim o        As Object
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    Set rs = Me.ListBox2.Recordset

    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If Nz(rs.Fields(0), "") = Me.ListBox1.Column(0) Then
            blnFound = True
            MsgBox "Found"
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: so Me.ListBox1.Column(0) looks at the value of the selected item in position 0...right?

Comment: That is correct. So just make sure to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I may have hit the answer button to quickly here...I keep getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error at rs.EOF

Comment: ok, so I did a .listcount and got a 1 back..but then in my when I do .column(0) to column(2) i get nulls back...whats weird is that I see text in the listbox though....

Comment: ok...so I ran this....Debug.Print "item added is: " & Me.lstbxSelectedPops.Column((0), 0) & ";" & Me.lstbxSelectedPops.Column((1), 0) & ";" & Me.lstbxSelectedPops.Column((2), 0)....and got values back...so why does EOF fail then?

Comment: The EOF isn't really the issue, it is the RS, what it seems to be saying is something about the RS is blank or something along those lines.  Can you post your EXACT code at in your main post?

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()
Dim i As Long
    For i = IIf(List2.ColumnHeads, 1, 0) To List2.ListCount - 1
        If List2.Column(1, i) = List0 Then
            MsgBox "Found"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that Column is zero based, so `Column(1, rowIndex)` is the second column in the list data.